# Problem with testing specific set of files

Tags: bash

I have a recursive function that goes through directories in which I know what files should I find, but not exact name. It's an image and three thumbnails. Thumbnails are having "1_", "2_" and "3_" prefix to the name of the original image.

I need to test if there are all 3 thumbnails, but must be 3 so I can delete original image file.

```sh
for d in $(find $s2 -maxdepth 3 -type d)
do
  echo $d #here is desired directory
  if [ -f "1_*.jpg" ]; then
    if [ -f "2_*.jpg" ]; then
      if [ -f "3_*.jpg"]; then
             # this doesn't work
             # but if it would I need to delete 
             # original 
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

So how can I test and then find what is a filename of original image to delete it?

Comment: The quotes around the filenames are preventing the glob characters (`*`) from being expanded. Try `if [ -f 1_*.jpg ]; then`, and note that you can use one compound test: `if [ -f "1_*.jpg" ] && [ -f 2_*.jpg ] && [ -f 3_*.jpg ]; then`

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not specific enough. Please [edit] and clarify what you mean. If there's an error message, include it. I say this because this code has a syntax error and an invalid bracket test. [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great resource for debugging btw.

Comment: You might want to read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a example of how you can do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
   dirname=$(dirname "$line")
   basename=$(basename "$line")
   if [[ -f "$dirname/1_$basename" &&  -f "$dirname/2_$basename" && -f "$dirname/3_$basename" ]]; then
      echo "3 thumbnails exists, you can remove $line!"
   fi   
done < <(find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.jpg" -not -name "[1-3]_*.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are interested in a list of files which are aggregated by the filename suffix (delimited by `_`).

This is what I did, see if it works for you...

The idea behind it to create an histogram (count the file appearances) and select only the files that have more than the threshold.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ touch x.jpg {1,2,3}_x.jpg 1_y.jpg {2,3}_z.jpg z.jpg
$ find * -type f -name '*.jpg' \
    | rev \
    | sort \
    | uniq \
    | cut -d _ -f 1 \
    | rev \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -n -k1 \
    | awk -v threshold=3 '$1 > threshold' \
    | awk '{print $2}'
```

This will give you an output of a file list which you probably want to delete.

In the snippet above, i create files with the pattern in your question to test my idea. you probably will not do that and will center your focus on the `find` command.

You might want to tweak the `find` command depending on the search depth\directories.

Comment: Thanks for efforts man! I really appreciate it. Solution below is exactly what I was after.

Comment: @EmilBeli: i am glad i could assist you. please accept my answer so all the others will know it is solved :)

Comment: but if I do, the other one is getting not accepted.

Comment: @EmilBeli: i am glad that you picked a solution. just wanted to make sure that your question is resolved.